# Lookup field appears as numerical values instead of text on Access report

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a report putting a field called `contact` which has the name of a person.  This name is linked directly to another table where I keep all the contacts.

For some strange reason, when I include this name (which in query view displays as the name of the contact), instead of the name appearing, the unique ID number is shown on my report.

Comment: Look [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm), specifically point #5.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I had no clue..  In your opinion, what is the best way around this problem and more importantly how to avoid it in the future??  It would be impossible to NOT use lookup fields in my databases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the [article](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm) cited in the above comment, you can use a Combo Box control on your report to do the lookup for you. To see how this can be done, create a new report based on the *table* containing the lookup field, then drag and drop that field onto the report. That will create a Combo Box control with properties that look something like this:

Row Source: `SELECT [Clients].[ID], [Clients].[LastName] FROM Clients;`
Bound Column: `1`
Column Count: `2`
Column Widths: `0";1"`

You could use a similar Combo Box control on your actual report to display the client's name rather than their numeric ID value.

Another alternative would be to change the `Control Source` of the report's Text Box control to have it do a `DLookUp()` on the table. If the lookup field is named [client] then changing the `Control Source` of the Text Box to something like

```
=DLookUp("LastName","Clients","ID=" & [client])
```

would also work.

Comment: Gord, you saved me again! Thank you very much.. Your a real wizard. A

Comment: Oh..its great..I have faced same problem and finally i found you..thank you so much @Gord

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add to the great answer by Gord:

When using a **"web" database** (started in Access 2007 I think), you cannot change a report's fields to `ComboBox` style, nor can you use `DLookUp()`. (web databases lack a ton of features)

The workaround for this, if you want to create a **Web-Report** that uses **lookup fields**, is to create a Web-Query first based on your Web-Table (all the *Web-** stuff has a www planet icon over the logo, if you create a new Web-DB in Access 2007+ you'll see what I mean)

So, instead of **Table -> Report**, you'll have to do **W-Table -> W-Query -> W-Report**.

Then, the only thing you need to customize to get the data right is the **W-Query**. Start by trying to reproduce the look in the query to match what you want users to see in the report. Note that here in the query, lookups will work fine (instead of the unique ID's, you get field names like you want). However, this will not carry over to the report. To do that, you gotta get the actual text field name you want into the query:

- You should already have one table in your query; start by **adding the table that your first lookup field points to**. For example, the table I want to print is called **`Stock_Boards`**, and it has a lookup field called **PCBID_lookup** that points to the table **`Stock_PCBs`**.
- Since you're using lookup fields, there should already be a **relationship line** between the two tables when you add the second one. If there isn't, something has gone horribly wrong.
- Now, see how that line connects two fields on the two different tables? For example, I've got my **PCBID_lookup** field on my **`Stock_Boards`** table, which connects to the **ID** field on my **`Stock_PCBs`** table. If I created a report from this now, **PCBID_lookup** would be a number, a number that correlates to the **ID** of a record on **`Stock_PCBs`**.
- To fix it, I will add the *name* field I want to show up on the report. In my example, that happens to be a Part Number, rather than the ID. I add the **PartNumber** field from my **`Stock_PCBs`** table to the query, and remove the **PCBID_lookup** field of the **`Stock_Boards`** table from my query.

  - Since **PartNumber** is what I want to show up on my report, it effectively replaces the original field (**PCBID_lookup**)
- Repeat for all lookup fields you want in your report.

  - I had 1 more: I removed the **Status** field of the **`Stock_Boards`** table (which was an *ID/Lookup*) and added the '**Status**' field from the **`Status`** table (which was the actual *text name*)

When finished, your query should look exactly how you want the data to appear, without any special tricks or asking Access to do something unnatural. Save your query, and create a web-report from it. Done!