# Lookup tables displaying number instead of text

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Currently I'm working on developing a mini access database but in one of my tables I have run into a look up problem where instead of returning the 'text' it returns the index. I can't seem to work out why the index is returned.

The query view highlights the information I'm after but the form view shows just the index. I have considered using dLookups for my table (tblDirectivesTask) in the following format but have been unsuccessful in having this work.

Lookupfield: owner
table: tblDirectivesTask

I have reviewed the following [Lookup field appears as numerical values instead of text on Access report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269387/lookup-field-appears-as-numerical-values-instead-of-text-on-access-report) which was useful, but I was not able to get to the solution that was provided.

Could anyone please point me in the correct direction?

Thank you.
[image: QueryView][image: Index View]

Comment: Maybe you should not start from there http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: Thanks for that! I re-read point #1 and realised I was actually indirectly referring to just the index instead of the actual source!